# Magento2.3: Display Custom text on Shipping Address

Tags: checkout, javascript, magento2.3, shipping-address

I would like to add custom text whenever shipping country is Sweden, Ive created Magento_Checkout module in my custom theme and added a phtml file

```
 <div class="free-shipping-info" data-bind="visible: showShippingCountryInfo()" style="display: none;">
    <div class="step-title" data-role="title" data-bind="i18n: 'Your country is sweden'"></div>
    <p class="desc" data-bind="i18n: 'sweden is a good place to live'"></p>
</div>
```

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="shipping-info-wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/country-component.js</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

For js

```
;define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',

], function (Component, ko) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-info'
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            var self = this._super();
            this.showShippingCountryInfo = ko.computed(function() {
                var method = country_id();

                if(method !== undefined) {
                    if(method === 'country_id_goes here') {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;

            }, this);
```

I would like to know if the js is correct.